# How often I have to send a device token to the server if I want to implement push notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to use Apple push notifications service in my application.I read several tutorials but nevertheless I didn't understand some things.It is said that I need to send periodically a device token to the server (in my case it's server written in PHP).But how often have I to send it and and how to generate the device token?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should register to push notifications each time your app starts (using `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`).
You should store the device token locally in your app each time it changes and send it to your server.
You should compare the device token you get from `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` to the last device token you stored. This way you can save some calls to your server (since in practice the device token rarely changes).

This is the registration code (taken from the Apple Push Notifications Programming Guide):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {

   // other setup tasks here....

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

}



// Delegation methods

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

    const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];

    self.registered = YES;

    [self sendProviderDeviceToken:devTokenBytes]; // custom method

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should send it every time your app starts or becomes active, since it could change at any time. The device token is given to you by the push notification API after it has successfully registered with Apple's servers.